# How many Apps can I add to my site?

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I added a lot of apps to my site, I need to know how many I can add (what is the limitation) and if this will effect my site performance at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Up to **2,000 apps (purchased from the store)** can be displayed on the Manage Licenses page. You can still manage the license of any app by going to the All Site Contents page of the site where the app is installed and clicking on Licenses.

When **more than 500 apps** from the corporate catalog are available to a single user, that user will no longer see any apps in the default Add an App view.

you can get more info about SP app limitations from [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/cc262787.aspx#SpApps)